# How can I overwrite/enhance Rails default db:... Rake tasks to do something different?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, migration

I am in the process of migrating a rails application which uses multi tenancy using Postgresql schemas (search_path) to be using rails built in multi database / horizontal sharing instead. In the process I need to be able to overwrite `db:..` tasks like `rails db:migrate`, `rails db:migrate:rollback` etc. etc. to be run against all my schemas.

I have tried:

```
#config/initializers/migrations.rb
module Migrations
  module DatabaseTasks
    def migrate(*)
      ["a", "b", "c"] do |schema|
        ActiveRecord::Base.connection.schema_search_path=schema
        puts "------------- migrating: #{schema} --------------"
        super
      end
    end
  end
end

ActiveSupport.on_load(:active_record) do
  ActiveRecord::Tasks::DatabaseTasks.singleton_class.prepend(Migrations::DatabaseTasks)
end
```

This works great for `rails db:migrate` - however it does not work for `rails db:migrate:down` or `rails db:rollback` as they do not invoke `ActiveRecord::Tasks::DatabaseTasks.migrate` see: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/bc2f390f7d2a96030532f41c08205f159e05af10/activerecord/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake#L260

I have also tried overwriting the rake tasks themselves:

```
# tasks/my_custom_db_tasks.rake
namespace :db do
  task migrate: :environment do |_task, _args|

    # Get a reference to the original db:migrate task
    original_migrate_task = Rake::Task['db:migrate']

    # Run the original migration task the specified number of times
    ["a", "b", "c"] do |schema|
      ActiveRecord::Base.connection.schema_search_path=schema
      puts "----------  migrating: #{schema} --------------"
      original_migrate_task.invoke
      original_migrate_task.reenable
    end
  end
end
```

But it's cumbersome to do for all tasks and it doesn't really work either as there seems to be something wrong with the way I try to overwrite the task definitions.

**My question is:** What would be the best way to generically hook into the `db:...` tests and run the original/"`super`" task a number of times?

Comment: *I need to be able to overwrite `db:..` tasks* Nothing in your post suggests that you need to overwrite the original tasks as opposed to building your own custom tasks and calling those instead.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to "enhance" rake tasks

One example I have used before is the following:

```rb
Rake::Task['db:migrate'].enhance ['db:my_task_before_migrate']
Rake::Task['db:rollback'].enhance ['db:my_task_before_rollback']

Rake::Task['db:migrate'].enhance do
  Rake::Task['db:my_task_after_migrate'].invoke
end

Rake::Task['db:rollback'].enhance do
  Rake::Task['db:my_task_after_rollback'].invoke
end
```

Note the distinction here between passing it as an argument and as a block.
When passed as an argument the task being passed is run *before* the task you enhance.

When passing it as a block, the task being invokes is run *after* the task being enhanced.